# Resolving trait implementation conflicts

Tags: generics, traits, rust

I'm trying to write some generic math functions in Rust and I keep running into the following error message:

```
error: conflicting implementations for trait SoAndSo
```

Is it possible to solve the problem? If so, how?

For example, I'm trying to write a generic dot product that takes two iterators, zips them and iterates over the pairs to accumulate the products. I want this function also to be able to compute complex-valued dot products. The dot product over complex numbers involves conjugating one side. My first idea was to write a trait `Dot1` for a binary function to replace `Mul` in that it also conjugates the left hand side argument. Here's the complete code:

```
extern crate num;

use num::complex::Complex;
use num::{Float, Num};

trait Dot1<Rhs, Result> {
    fn dot1(&self, rhs: Rhs) -> Result;
}

impl<T: Float> Dot1<T, T> for T {
    // conjugation for reals is a no-op
    fn dot1(&self, rhs: T) -> T {
        *self * rhs
    }
}

impl<T: Num + Clone> Dot1<Complex<T>, Complex<T>> for Complex<T> {
    fn dot1(&self, rhs: Complex<T>) -> Complex<T> {
        self.conj() * rhs
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!")
}
```

Since a `Complex<T>` is not `Float`, there should be no overlap between the two "generic impls". I didn't expect any problems, but every time I try to provide more than one "generic impl" for a trait, the compiler doesn't like it:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `Dot1<num::Complex<_>, num::Complex<_>>` for type `num::Complex<_>`:
  --> src/main.rs:17:1
   |
10 | impl<T: Float> Dot1<T, T> for T {
   | ------------------------------- first implementation here
...
17 | impl<T: Num + Clone> Dot1<Complex<T>, Complex<T>> for Complex<T> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation for `num::Complex<_>`
   |
   = note: upstream crates may add new impl of trait `num::Float` for type `num::Complex<_>` in future versions
```

How can I write a generic, iterator-based dot product that works for both real and complex numbers? Taking the iterators, zipping them, etc. is not a problem and I was even able to figure out what type parameters to use with which bounds. I don't seem able to "unify" certain data types using traits such as the one from above.

Comment: this will be possible when [PR 48](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/48) is implemented

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is the (current) compiler does not register that `Complex<T>` does not implement `Float`. Imagine if `Complex` did implement `Float`: either there would have to be some way to decide which `impl` to use, or the overlapping code would have to be outlawed... but what if someone only adds the `impl<T> Float for Complex<T>` in some other crate the compiler doesn't know about?

This last point is key: unlike Haskell, Rust's design allows this code to be perfectly OK without any risk, all because Rust differs in how it handles the last point. If you are in a crate that can see a type `Type` and a trait `Trait`, then you know for 100% sure if `Type` implements `Trait`: Rust doesn't have Haskell's open world assumption, as you can only write `impl Trait for Type` if either `Trait` or `Type` lie in the current crate (compilation unit), that is, you can't have [orphan instances](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Orphan_instance), where someone implements `Float` for `Complex<T>` in some distant crate.

RFC 24 (that Chris links to) [recognises this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/active/0024-traits.md#coherence), allowing these generic implementations to coexist with more specific ones, as long as the implementations are guaranteed to not overlap.

Comment: What about `Complex<T>` being "more specialized" than `T`? Shouldn't that count for something? Sorry, but what was the reason again to ditch that kind of behaviour including overload resolution à la C++? Please help a C++ programmer to understand the Rust design choices.

Comment: There's no recognition of specialisation in Rust (yet). E.g. you would need to have some way to resolve which `impl` to use for `(uint, uint)` given `impl<T> Trait for (uint, T)` and `impl<T> Trait for (T, uint)`. Philosophically, Haskell's system is similar, and you need to explicitly opt-in to these sort of `impl`s there via language extensions, however, the main problems there don't necessarily apply to Rust (same as those described in this answer). Some form of `impl` specificity may be added in the (long-term) future.