# How can an operator be overloaded for different RHS types and return values?

Tags: operator-overloading, rust

Given the following struct:

```
struct Vector3D {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
    z: f32
}
```

I want to overload its `*` operator to do a dot product when the right hand side is a `Vector3D`, and to do an element-wise multiplication when the RHS is a `f32`. My code looks like this:

```
// Multiplication with scalar
impl Mul<f32, Vector3D> for Vector3D {
    fn mul(&self, f: &f32) -> Vector3D {
        Vector3D {x: self.x * *f, y: self.y * *f, z: self.z * *f} 
    }   
}
// Multiplication with vector, aka dot product
impl Mul<Vector3D, f32> for Vector3D {
    fn mul(&self, other: &Vector3D) -> f32 {
        self.x * other.x + self.y * other.y + self.z * other.z
    }   
}
```

The compiler says for the first impl block:

```
Vector3D.rs:40:1: 44:2 error: conflicting implementations for trait `std::ops::Mul`
Vector3D.rs:40 impl Mul<f32, Vector3D> for Vector3D { 
...
Vector3D.rs:53:1: 57:2 note: note conflicting implementation here
Vector3D.rs:53 impl Mul<Vector3D, f32> for Vector3D { 
...
```

and vice versa for the other implementation.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24554738/rust-resolving-trait-impl-conflicts.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan it's not really a duplicate. This question has two concrete `impl`s, while that question has a generic `impl` along with a concrete one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At the moment only a single `impl` is allowed per trait-type pair.

This situation will be *improved* with [RFC 48](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0048-traits.md), but it's not the full story (it's not really any of the story). The relevant section is [Coherence](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0048-traits.md#coherence), and it certainly doesn't mention the operator overloading case specifically, and essentially says it is still illegal:

> The following example is NOT OK:
>
> ```
> trait Iterator<E> { ... }
> impl Iterator<char> for ~str  { ... }
> impl Iterator<u8> for ~str { ... }
> ```

Niko Matsakis (author of that RFC & Rust-type-system expert) has been thinking about these overloading traits specifically: he is the one who [published](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2012/10/04/refining-traits-slash-impls/) ("What if I want overloading?") the trick below, but he has expressed his distaste towards it, mentioning that he'd like to allow implementations as you have written...

... which is where his [RFC 135](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0135-where.md) comes in. The situation is described in detail in ["multidispatch traits"](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0135-where.md#multidispatch-traits).

---

You can work-around it for now using secondary traits. The extra layer of traits allows you to write just one `impl Mul<...> for Vector3D` but comes at the cost of requiring a new trait for each type for which you wish to have multiple implementations of `Mul`.

```
#[deriving(Show)]
struct Vector3D {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
    z: f32
}

trait MulVec3D<Res> {
    fn do_mul(&self, v: &Vector3D) -> Res;
}

// Multiplication with scalar
impl MulVec3D<Vector3D> for f32 {
   fn do_mul(&self, v: &Vector3D) -> Vector3D {
       Vector3D {x: v.x * *self, y: v.y * *self, z: v.z * *self} 
   }
}
// Multiplication with vector, aka dot product
impl MulVec3D<f32> for Vector3D {
    fn do_mul(&self, v: &Vector3D) -> f32 {
        self.x * v.x + self.y * v.y + self.z * v.z
    }
}

impl<Res, RHS: MulVec3D<Res>>  Mul<RHS, Res> for Vector3D {
    fn mul(&self, rhs: &RHS) -> Res {
        rhs.do_mul(self)
    }   
}

fn main() {
    let a = Vector3D { x: 1.0, y: 2.0, z: 3.0 };
    let b = Vector3D { x: -3.0, y: 2.0, z: -1.0 };

    println!("{}, {}", a * 2f32, a * b); // Vector3D { x: 2, y: 4, z: 6 }, -2
}
```

Comment: This solution seems to be outdated and gives compiler errors. Shepmaster's answer seems to fit the bill.

Answer (score 49):

As of Rust 1.0, you can now implement this:

```
use std::ops::Mul;

#[derive(Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct Vector3D {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
    z: f32,
}

// Multiplication with scalar
impl Mul<f32> for Vector3D {
    type Output = Vector3D;

    fn mul(self, f: f32) -> Vector3D {
        Vector3D {
            x: self.x * f,
            y: self.y * f,
            z: self.z * f,
        }
    }
}

// Multiplication with vector, aka dot product
impl Mul<Vector3D> for Vector3D {
    type Output = f32;

    fn mul(self, other: Vector3D) -> f32 {
        self.x * other.x + self.y * other.y + self.z * other.z
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Vector3D {
        x: 1.0,
        y: 2.0,
        z: 3.0,
    };
    let b = a * -1.0;
    let c = a * b;

    println!("{:?}", a);
    println!("{:?}", b);
    println!("{:?}", c);
}
```

The big change that allows this is the introduction of *associated types*, which shows up as the `type Output =` bit in each implementation. Another notable change is that the operator traits now take arguments by value, consuming them, so I went ahead and implemented `Copy` for the struct.