# How do you implement specific types on generic traits in rust?

Tags: rust

I initially assumed you could do this, because the documentation (http://doc.rust-lang.org/rust.html#implementations) suggests you can:

```
trait Bar<T> {
  fn ex(&self) -> T;
}

struct Foo {
  y:f64
}

impl Bar<int> for Foo {
  fn ex(&self) -> int {
    return self.y.floor() as int;
  }
}

impl Bar<uint> for Foo {
  fn ex(&self) -> uint {
    if (self.y < 0.0) {
      return 0u;
    }
    return self.y.floor() as uint;
  }
}
```

...but that doesn't seem to work. I get errors like:

```
error: multiple applicable methods in scope
error: expected Bar<uint>, but found Bar<int> (expected uint but found int)
error: expected Bar<int>, but found Bar<uint> (expected int but found uint)
```

So I figured perhaps Foo has to be generic for this to work, so each specific Foo has it's own Bar implementation on it:

```
trait Bar<T> {
  fn ex(&self) -> T;
}

struct Foo<T> {
  y:f64
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
  fn new<U>(value:f64) -> Foo<U> {
    return Foo { y: value } as Foo<U>;
  }
}

impl Bar<int> for Foo<int> {
  fn ex(&self) -> int {
    return self.y.floor() as int;
  }
}

impl Bar<uint> for Foo<uint> {
  fn ex(&self) -> uint {
    if (self.y < 0.0) {
      return 0u;
    }
    return self.y.floor() as uint;
  }
}

fn main() {
  let z = Foo::new::<int>(100.5);
  let q = Foo::new::<uint>(101.5);
  let i:int = z.ex();
  let j:uint = q.ex();
}
```

...but my constructor seems to not work:

```
x.rs:11:12: 11:38 error: non-scalar cast: `Foo<<generic #1>>` as `Foo<U>`
x.rs:11     return Foo { y: value } as Foo<U>;
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Edit: I also tried:

```
impl<T> Foo<T> {
  fn new<U>(value:f64) -> Foo<U> {
    let rtn:Foo<U> = Foo { y: value };
    return rtn;
  }
}
```

Which solve the casting error, but results in:

```
x.rs:32:11: 32:26 error: cannot determine a type for this expression: unconstrained type
x.rs:32   let z = Foo::new::<int>(100.5);
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

O_o I have no idea what that means.

How do you do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `impl Bar<int> for Foo` and `impl Bar<uint> for Foo` is an error because, at the moment, only one `impl` is allowed per trait, type pair (ignoring parameters on the trait). [I went into more detail in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24594911/1256624), including a work around using a secondary trait that avoids having to make `Foo` generic (which is probably not what you want).

```
trait BarForFoo {
    fn do_ex(foo: &Foo) -> Self;
}
impl BarForFoo for int {
    fn do_ex(foo: &Foo) -> int {
        foo.y.floor() as int
    }
}    
impl BarForFoo for uint {
    fn do_ex(foo: &Foo) -> uint {
        foo.y.max(0.0).floor() as uint
    }
}

impl<T: BarForFoo> Bar<T> for Foo {
    fn ex(&self) -> T { BarForFoo::do_ex(self) }
}
```

---

The second error is because you have two type parameters `T` and `U` "in scope" for the `new` function, but are only specifying one (`U`). The `T` needs to be specified by writing `Foo::<int>::...`, however I don't think this is what you want, instead, you should be using the `T` generic in the `new` function:

```
impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn new(value: f64) -> Foo<T> { ... }
}
```

As background, the compiler needs to know the concrete type of `T` because the implementation of `new` could change:

```
impl<T> Foo<T> {
  fn new<U>(value:f64) -> Foo<U> {
    Foo { y: value + std::mem::size_of::<T>() as f64 }
  }
}
```

and then `Foo::<()>::new::<int>(0.0)` would give `y == 0.0`, but `Foo::<u64>::new::<int>(0.0)` would give `y == 8.0`.

Comment: Great answer~ I wonder if you could just clarify one little point from the second part. impl<T> Foo<T> { fn new<T>() -> Array<T> } doesn't work either. It still errors about unconstrained type. However, if I remove new from impl<T> Foo<T> {} and put it in impl Foo<()> { } it works fine. Why is that? Why does the -> Array<U> not infer Array::<U> on the return type? ...and what is this <()> thing that makes it work?

Comment: @Doug the first case is defining a new type parameter also called `T`, the same as `let a = 1; { let a = 2; }` is defining a new variable `a` inside the inner scope. The `Foo<()>` case works because you then only have the type parameter from the `new<T>() -> Array<T>`, as you've specified a concrete type ([`()`, aka unit](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/unit/primitive.unit.html)) for the type parameter of `Foo`: it's no longer generic. The `-> Array<U>` does not infer the return type because that would be wrong, there's no reason that the `U` and the `T` have to be the same...

Comment: E.g. you might have `impl<T> Array<T> { fn convert<U>(&self) -> Array<U> { ... } }` that is making an array of a different type: just because you mention `Array<...>` doesn't mean it has to match the `Array<...>` in the `impl` header.

Comment: (To be clear, the `<()>` thing is just passing the `()` type as a type parameter, `impl Foo<uint> { ... }` would also "work" equally well, but almost certainly is not what you actually want.)

Comment: @Doug This restriction has been removed by [RFC 0048](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0048-traits.md), multiple (trait, type) pairs are now allowed when the type parameters differ.