# Is it possible to implement the equals operator for different types in Rust?

Tags: rust

As seen in [How can an operator be overloaded for different RHS types and return values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594374/overload-operators-with-different-rhs-type/24594911#24594911) you can implement some operators, eg. Add on multiple types using a work around.

Is a similar thing possible for the PartialEq trait?

I've tried various things, but the closest I can get is creating a fake trait Foo, implementing PartialEq on &Foo (since it's a trait you can't implement it on Foo) and then doing:

```
let x:Bar = ...
let y:FooBar = ...
if &x as &Foo == &y as &Foo {
  ...
}
```

The Equiv trait looks like it should be used for this, but as far as I can tell, implementing Equiv doesn't have anything to do with the == operator.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `==` operator is only overridable via the `PartialEq` trait, and thus usable with matching types. Any other form of equality/equivalence needs a custom function/method, you can use the `Equiv` trait, although values that are `equiv`alent should theoretically also have the same hash (or else [`HashMap.find_equiv`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/collections/hashmap/struct.HashMap.html#method.find_equiv) won't work as you expect).

Answer (score 2):

### `PartialEq` implementations can take any right-hand side type

As of Rust 1.0.0 (2015), [`PartialEq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html) (`==` and `!=`) allows you to supply any type (sized or not) as the right-hand side's type when you are implementing it. You can also use traits as both the left-hand and right-hand side when implementing `PartialEq`.

#### Comparing two different types

Implementing `PartialEq` for two different types is very simple. The trait `PartialEq` takes a generic type called `Rhs` that specifies what type you will be comparing with the type that you are implementing `PartialEq` for.

```rust
impl PartialEq<B> for A {
    fn eq(&self, other: &B) -> bool {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

#### Comparing any types that implement a specific trait

You can use the [`dyn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.dyn.html)
<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50650071/4709300)</sup> keyword to specify a trait as a type, which allows us to implement `PartialEq` for or with that trait.

```rust
trait Foo { /* ... */ }
impl PartialEq<dyn Foo> for dyn Foo {
    fn eq(&self, other: &dyn Foo) -> bool {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

---

#### Working example of two-type `==`

Below is a working example of writing and testing `PartialEq` between two different structs, `A` and `B`.

```rust
struct A {
    thing: String,
    stuff: u8,
}

struct B {
    optional_thing: Option<String>,
    extra: String,
}

impl PartialEq<B> for A {
    fn eq(&self, other: &B) -> bool {
        if let Some(thing_b) = &other.optional_thing {
            *thing_b == self.thing
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a1 = A {
        thing: "Hello".to_owned(),
        stuff: 0,
    };
    let a2 = A {
        thing: "World".to_owned(),
        stuff: 32,
    };

    let b1 = B {
        optional_thing: Some("Hello".to_owned()),
        extra: "...".to_owned(),
    };
    let b2 = B {
        optional_thing: None,
        extra: "".to_owned(),
    };

    assert!(a1 == b1, "a1 and b1 should be equal");
    assert!(a1 != b2, "a1 should not equal b2");

    assert!(a2 != b1, "a2 should not equal b1");
    assert!(a2 != b2, "a2 should not equal b2");
}
```