# Several implementations of the Add trait for the same type

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to do something very simple like that:

```
fn main() {   
   #[deriving(Show)]
   struct A {
      a: int
   }

   impl Add<A, A> for A {
      fn add(&self, other: &A) -> A {
         A { a: self.a + other.a }
      }
   }

   impl Add<int, A> for A {
      fn add(&self, v: &int) -> A {
         A { a: self.a + *v }
      }
   }   

   let x = A { a: 10 } + A { a: 20 };

   println!("x: {}", x);
}
```

Rust compile doesn't like my code and says:

```
src/sandbox.rs:20:12: 20:37 error: multiple applicable methods in scope [E0034]
src/sandbox.rs:20    let x = A { a: 10 } + A { a: 20 };
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/sandbox.rs:8:7: 10:8 note: candidate #1 is `main::A.Add<A, A>::add`
src/sandbox.rs:8       fn add(&self, other: &A) -> A {
src/sandbox.rs:9          A { a: self.a + other.a }
src/sandbox.rs:10       }
src/sandbox.rs:14:7: 16:8 note: candidate #2 is `main::A.Add<int, A>::add`
src/sandbox.rs:14       fn add(&self, v: &int) -> A {
src/sandbox.rs:15          A { a: self.a + *v }
src/sandbox.rs:16       }
```

Ultimately I want to add an int to my type A like that:

```
let x: A = A { a: 10 } + A { a: 20 };
let y: A = A { a: 10 } + 20i;
let z: A = A 10i + { a: 20 };
```

What is the best approach?

Comment: There is no support for many trait implementations for the same type, you can use this workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594374/overload-operators-with-different-rhs-type

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update:

**YES, you can implement this now!**

How? In similar manner to below:

```
use std::ops::Add;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct A {
      a: i32,
}


impl Add<i32> for A {
    type Output = A;

    fn add(self, _rhs: i32) -> A {
        A { a : self.a + _rhs }
    }
}

impl Add<A> for A {
    type Output = A;

    fn add(self, _rhs: A) -> A {
        A { a : self.a + _rhs.a }
    }
}

fn main() {   
    let x = A { a: 10 } + A { a: 20 };
    let y = A { a: 40 } + 2; 

    println!("x: {:?}\ny: {:?}", x, y);
}
```

---

Explanation. See when you write

```
let x = A { a: 10 } + A { a: 20 };
```

Rust looks up all Add traits implemented `for A`. Problem is because there are two defined: `impl Add<A, A> for A` and `impl Add<int, A> for A` Rust is 'unsure' which one to take. Don't quote me on this, because Rust compiler internals are not my cup of tea, but I think Rust team wanted to avoid paying the price of having multi dispatch.

Your solution is to either:
A) Add another trait like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594374/overload-operators-with-different-rhs-type) that will do the addition for you like in example given.
B) Wait for associative types to land, which is the better bet. ( [Issue #17307](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/17307)  )
C) Give up on `impl Add<int, A> for A`.

I think what you want is multi-dispatch which should be landing soon. See this [RFC #195](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0195-associated-items.md) for details.

Comment: I think it's not a performance issue but more a concern about ambiguity and "crate composability". I hope multiple dispatch will land soon. It's very useful for these kinds of binary operators at least.