# Mismatched types when returning the result of adding two generics

Tags: rust

I am learning Rust, have read the Rust homepage, and am trying out small example programs. Here is code that fails:

```
use std::ops::Add;

pub struct Complex<T> {
    pub re: T,
    pub im: T,
}

impl <T: Add> Add<Complex<T>> for Complex<T> {
    type Output = Complex<T>;
    fn add(self, other: Complex<T>) -> Complex<T> {
        Complex {re: self.re + other.re, im: self.im + other.im}
    }
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
src/lib.rs:11:3: 11:59 error: mismatched types:
 expected `Complex<T>`,
    found `Complex<<T as core::ops::Add>::Output>`
(expected type parameter,
    found associated type) [E0308]
src/lib.rs:11       Complex {re: self.re + other.re, im: self.im + other.im}
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I don't understand why it fails to compile.

Answer (score 6):

The [`Add` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html) is defined as

```
pub trait Add<RHS = Self> {
    type Output;
    fn add(self, rhs: RHS) -> Self::Output;
}
```

That is, given a type for `Self` (the type the trait is implemented for), and a type for the right-hand-side (`RHS`, the thing being added), there will be a unique type that is produced: `Output`.

Conceptually, this allows you to create a type `A` that can have a type `B` added to it, which will always produce a third type `C`.

In your example, you have constrained `T` to implement `Add`. By default, the `RHS` type is assumed to be the same as the type the trait is implemented for (`RHS = Self`). However, there are no restrictions placed on what the *output type* must be.

There are two potential solutions:

1. Say that you will return a `Complex` that has been parameterized by whatever the result type of adding `T` is:

   ```
   impl<T> Add<Complex<T>> for Complex<T>
   where
       T: Add,
   {
       type Output = Complex<T::Output>;

       fn add(self, other: Complex<T>) -> Complex<T::Output> {
           Complex {
               re: self.re + other.re,
               im: self.im + other.im,
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Restrict `T` to those types that when added to themselves return the same type:

   ```
   impl<T> Add<Complex<T>> for Complex<T>
   where
       T: Add<Output = T>,
   {
       type Output = Complex<T>;

       fn add(self, other: Complex<T>) -> Complex<T> {
           Complex {
               re: self.re + other.re,
               im: self.im + other.im,
           }
       }
   }
   ```

See also:

- [How do I require a generic type implement an operation like Add, Sub, Mul, or Div in a generic function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29184358/155423)
- [How to write a trait bound for adding two references of a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34630695/155423)

Answer (score 4):

Your implementation of `add` produces a `Complex<<T as core::ops::Add>::Output>`. `<T as core::ops::Add>::Output` (i.e. the `Output` of the implementation of `Add<T>` for `T`) is not guaranteed to be the same as `T`. You can add a constraint on the `Output` associated type to restrict your implementation to be only available when they are in fact the same:

```
impl<T: Add<Output = T>> Add for Complex<T> {
    type Output = Complex<T>;

    fn add(self, other: Complex<T>) -> Complex<T> {
        Complex { re: self.re + other.re, im: self.im + other.im }
    }
}
```

Or, you could change your implementation to be as generic as possible by making it possible to add a `Complex<T>` and a `Complex<U>`, provided that it is possible to add a `T` and a `U`, and by returning a `Complex<<T as Add<U>>::Output>`.

```
impl<T: Add<U>, U> Add<Complex<U>> for Complex<T> {
    type Output = Complex<<T as Add<U>>::Output>;

    fn add(self, other: Complex<U>) -> Self::Output {
        Complex { re: self.re + other.re, im: self.im + other.im }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the output type of `Add` for `T`:

```
impl <T: Add<Output = T>> Add for Complex<T> {
    type Output = Complex<T>;
    fn add(self, other: Complex<T>) -> Complex<T> {
        Complex {re: self.re + other.re, im: self.im + other.im}
    }
}
```