# Why can I not dereference or add a generic type even though I'm passing in a type that can be dereferenced and added?

Tags: rust

I have some problems with a generic implementation of a method:

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use global::entity::EntityId;

struct simple_system<T> {
    list_sum: BTreeMap<EntityId, T>,
    list_com: BTreeMap<EntityId, Vec<T>>,
}

impl<T> simple_system<T> {
    pub fn new() -> simple_system<T> {
        simple_system {
            list_sum: BTreeMap::new(),
            list_com: BTreeMap::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn addComponent(&mut self, id: EntityId, comp: T) {
        self.list_com.entry(id).or_insert_with(Vec::new).push(comp);
        match self.list_sum.get_mut(&id) {
            Some(v) => *v = *v + *comp,
            None => self.list_sum.insert(id, comp),
        }
    }
}
```

with the following errors.

```
error[E0614]: type `T` cannot be dereferenced
  --> src/main.rs:20:34
   |
20 |             Some(v) => *v = *v + *comp,
   |                                  ^^^^^

error[E0369]: binary operation `+` cannot be applied to type `T`
  --> src/main.rs:20:29
   |
20 |             Some(v) => *v = *v + *comp,
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: an implementation of `std::ops::Add` might be missing for `T`
```

I don't know what I have to change to get it to work. I use it with `u32` type so it should have an `+` operator.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example (apart from your actual problem), e.g. include some stub `EntityId`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29184358/requiring-implementation-of-mul-in-generic-function (but not a duplicate imho: the OP in the linked question already knew to use traits, just now how)

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115337/function-generics-an-implementation-of-stdopsadd-might-be-missing-for-t (which shouldn't have been closed as duplicate)

Comment: The Rust standard naming is `PascalCase` for types and `snake_case` for function and variable names; please adopt it.

Comment: @Stefan *which shouldn't have been closed as duplicate* — see how it says "marked as duplicate by [...] Community"? That means that [the OP voted to close it as a duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287763/155423).

Comment: You should **always** write the non-generic version first. Only when that works should you make it generic. For example, a `u32` **cannot be dereferenced**, so I don't even know what your code would be doing.

Comment: I will try this. Maybe it enlightens me a little bit. :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here the Solution:

1. At first you should write a working non generic (c++ template) version and then evolve it to a generic version.

   ```
   use std::collections::BTreeMap;

   #[derive(Debug)]
   struct SumUpSystem {
       list_sum: BTreeMap<u64, i32 >,
       list_com: BTreeMap<u64, Vec<i32> >
   }

   impl SumUpSystem {
       pub fn new() -> SumUpSystem {
           SumUpSystem {
               list_sum: BTreeMap::new(),
               list_com: BTreeMap::new()
           }
       }

       pub fn add_component(&mut self, id: u64, comp: i32) {
           self.list_com.entry(id).or_insert_with(Vec::new).push(comp);

           let mut insert = false;
           match self.list_sum.get_mut(&id) {
               Some(x) => *x = *x + comp,
               None => insert = true
           }

           if (insert) {
               self.list_sum.insert(id, comp);
           }
       }

       pub fn sum(& self, id: u64) -> i32 {
           if let Some(x) = self.list_sum.get(&id) {
               *x
           } else {
               panic!("Invalid id: Not in system!");
           }
       }
   }

   #[cfg(test)]
   mod test {
       use super::*;

       macro_rules! init_test {
           ($v:ident) => (let mut $v : SumUpSystem = SumUpSystem::new(););
       }

       #[test]
       fn add_component() {
           init_test!(s);
           s.add_component(1, 13);
           assert_eq!(s.sum(1), 13);
           s.add_component(1, 26);
           assert_eq!(s.sum(1), 13 + 26);
       }
   }
   ```
2. The generic (c++ template). You should read the Trait section of the Rust Documentation to understand how/why it works.

   ```
   use std::collections::BTreeMap;
   use std::ops::Add;

   #[derive(Debug)]
   struct SumUpSystem<T> {
       list_sum: BTreeMap<u64, T >,
       list_com: BTreeMap<u64, Vec<T> >
   }

   impl <T: Add<Output=T> + Clone> SumUpSystem<T> {
       pub fn new() -> SumUpSystem<T> {
           SumUpSystem {
               list_sum: BTreeMap::new(),
               list_com: BTreeMap::new()
           }
       }

       pub fn add_component(&mut self, id: u64, comp: &T) {
           self.list_com.entry(id).or_insert_with(Vec::new).push(comp.clone());

           let mut insert = false;
           match self.list_sum.get_mut(&id) {
               Some(x) => *x = x.clone() + comp.clone(),
               None => insert = true
           }

           if insert {
               self.list_sum.insert(id, comp.clone());
           }
       }

       pub fn sum(& self, id: u64) -> T {
           if let Some(x) = self.list_sum.get(&id) {
               x.clone()
           } else {
               panic!("Invalid id: Not in system!");
           }
       }
   }

   #[cfg(test)]
   mod test {
       use super::*;

       macro_rules! init_test {
           ($v:ident) => (let mut $v : SumUpSystem<i32> = SumUpSystem::new(););
       }

       #[test]
       fn add_component() {
           init_test!(s);
           s.add_component(1, &13i32);
           assert_eq!(s.sum(1), 13i32);
           s.add_component(1, &26i32);
           assert_eq!(s.sum(1), 39i32);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 5):

The Rust generics systems doesn't work the way C++ templates do: in C++ the compiler doesn't check whether the code actually compiles with any type in advance.

Rust makes sure the function compiles with any type that fulfills the listed requirements (called [trait bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-02-traits.html#trait-bounds)).  The compiler already told you what is missing: `std::ops::Add` might be missing for `T`, so ask for it:

```
impl<T: Add<Output = T>> simple_system<T> { /* … */ }
```

This will not fix everything; your code has other issues as well.