# How can I accept an arbitrary container that is sliceable by `..`?

Tags: rust

I have the following simple setup:

```
pub trait Distribution {
    type T;
    fn sample(&self) -> Self::T;
}

pub fn foo<D, U>(dist: &D, f: &Fn(&[f64]))
where
    D: Distribution<T = U>,
    U: std::ops::Index<usize>,
{
    let s = dist.sample();
    f(&s[..]);
}
```

`foo` accepts a generic container that implements `Distribution` and a function, but if I use it in an example like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d3034d9fe5c2a24fb90713f8a8c2043d&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015):

```
struct Normal {}

impl Distribution for Normal {
    type T = Vec<f64>;
    fn sample(&self) -> Self::T {
        vec![0.0]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Normal {};
    let f = |_x: &[f64]| {};
    foo(&x, &f);
}
```

It does not work, because `f(&s[..]);` is not of type slice:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:12:10
   |
12 |     f(&s[..]);
   |          ^^ expected usize, found struct `std::ops::RangeFull`
   |
   = note: expected type `usize`
              found type `std::ops::RangeFull`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:12:7
   |
12 |     f(&s[..]);
   |       ^^^^^^ expected slice, found associated type
   |
   = note: expected type `&[f64]`
              found type `&<U as std::ops::Index<usize>>::Output`
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You say that you are going to index your slice with a `usize`:

> ```
> U: std::ops::Index<usize>,
> ```

Then you index the slice by something that is **not a `usize`**:

> ```
> f(&s[..]);
> ```

This is a [`RangeFull`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeFull.html). Rightly, the compiler doesn't allow you to lie to it about types.

Instead, if you use the correct types, as shown in the error message, it works:

```
U: std::ops::Index<std::ops::RangeFull>,
```

Then the error is about the output type of the indexing. See [Requiring implementation of Mul in generic function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29184358/155423) for a full description.

```
U: std::ops::Index<std::ops::RangeFull, Output = [f64]>,
```

---

That being said...

1. There's no reason to introduce the generic type `U`. Instead, add trait bounds on the associated type of `D`.
2. It's unlikely that you wish to force dynamic dispatch of your closure. Instead, take it as a generic type:

```
use std::ops::{Index, RangeFull};

pub fn foo<D, F>(dist: &D, f: F)
where
    D: Distribution,
    D::T: Index<RangeFull, Output = [f64]>,
    F: Fn(&[f64]),
{
    let s = dist.sample();
    f(&s[..]);
}
```

Or equivalently:

```
pub fn foo<D>(dist: &D, f: impl Fn(&[f64]))
where
    D: Distribution,
    D::T: std::ops::Index<std::ops::RangeFull, Output = [f64]>,
```

However, using `RangeFull` for this level of generic doesn't feel right to me. I'd use [`AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) instead:

```
pub fn foo<D>(dist: &D, f: impl Fn(&[f64]))
where
    D: Distribution,
    D::T: AsRef<[f64]>,
{
    let s = dist.sample();
    f(s.as_ref());
}
```

Comment: Very nice! It works! Good explanation as well. And thanks for editing the original question as well!