# How do I declare a generic function which can add together references to sparse vectors?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use [the `sprs` crate](https://crates.io/crates/sprs) (version `0.6.3`) to manipulate sparse vectors. I'd like to add two vectors together.
I started off with an implementation of the `Add` trait, then simplified this to an implementation function. Finally, I've boiled down the problem to a simple generic function.

```rust
// This works: the scalar type `u64` is fixed here
fn adder(first: &CsVec<u64>, second: &CsVec<u64>) -> CsVec<u64> {
    first + second
}

// When I try to make the scalar type generic, it doesn't work
fn adder2<T>(first: &CsVec<T>, second: &CsVec<T>) -> CsVec<T>
where
    CsVec<T>: Add,
    T: Add + Debug,
{
    first + second
}
```

The first version compiles fine, but I'd like to know why the second version won't compile. I get this error message:

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `+` cannot be applied to type `&sprs::sparse::CsVecBase<std::vec::Vec<usize>, std::vec::Vec<T>>`
  --> libp3prime/src/lib/datacache.rs:62:5
   |
62 |     first + second
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: an implementation of `std::ops::Add` might be missing for `&sprs::sparse::CsVecBase<std::vec::Vec<usize>, std::vec::Vec<T>>`
```

I don't really understand the error message. I know that you can add two `CsVecs` together, since `adder()` compiles, so I am a bit lost.

The two vectors should add together.

Comment: @E_net4  OP mentioned [sprs 
 crate where CsVec structure is defined](https://docs.rs/sprs/0.2.0/sprs/sparse/vec/struct.CsVec.html)

Comment: I believe the question does meet the MCVE standards. I did note that CsVec was part of the sprs crate (someone has kindly edited my question to add a link to the crate) and expected that anyone wanting to know the implementation of CsVec would look at the sprs documentation. Apart from that, I believed that all the information required was present.

Comment: After answering, I found this question: [How do I require a generic type implement an operation like Add, Sub, Mul, or Div in a generic function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29184358/3650362) Is this close enough to flag as a duplicate?

Comment: @trentcl I did search and failed to find that. That is close enough to flag as duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Be sure that the trait bounds *defined on* the function match the behavior *used in* the function.

`first` and `second` are not `CsVec<T>`, but `&CsVec<T>`. In Rust, `&X` is a different type from `X`. You need a trait bound that says that you can add two `&CsVec<T>`s and get a `CsVec<T>` as output:

```
fn adder2<'a, T>(first: &'a CsVec<T>, second: &'a CsVec<T>) -> CsVec<T>
where
    &'a CsVec<T>: Add<Output = CsVec<T>>,
{
    first + second
}
```

No bounds on `T` are needed in this example.

The `'a` lifetime parameter in this case was passed in to the function. Sometimes it is useful to define a trait bound on a reference *inside* the function, for example, to use `+` on references to local variables. In that case you would want to use the *higher-ranked trait bound* `for<'a> &'a CsVec<T>: Add<Output = CsVec<T>>` instead. See the linked questions below for more information.

Lukas Kalbertodt points out that it may sometimes be more flexible to say "I just want to add two `&CsVec<T>`s, and I will return whatever type that operation gives me", which you can do by returning `<&'a CsVec<T> as Add>::Output`:

```
fn adder2<'a, T>(first: &'a CsVec<T>, second: &'a CsVec<T>) -> <&'a CsVec<T> as Add>::Output
where
    &'a CsVec<T>: Add,
{
    first + second
}
```

In this case the output type does not have to be exactly `CsVec<T>`, but when it is, it works the same way as the first version.

### Related

- [How to write a trait bound for adding two references of a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34630695/3650362)
- [How do I require a generic type implement an operation like Add, Sub, Mul, or Div in a generic function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29184358/3650362)

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt: Thanks to both of you! That makes lifetimes and their usage a lot clearer for me.