# Automatically forward operations while keeping the result wrapped

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a nice interface for physics measures like angles, mass, velocities, etc. I want them to offer dimensional analysis checking at compile-time, ideally with zero runtime overhead. I think Rust could be very well-suited for this, especially with traits.

What I have so far looks something like this:

```
pub trait Measure {
    type Underlying: Clone; // the underlying storage type (most often a Float)

    fn name() -> &'static str;
    fn default_unit() -> &'static str;
    fn in_default_unit(&self) -> Self::Underlying;
    fn from_default_unit(m: Self::Underlying) -> Self;
}
```

and an implementation would be something like:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
pub struct Angle<'a> {
    radians: Float, // dynamic but either a `f64` or `f32`
}

impl<'a> Angle<'a> {
    fn from_radians(radians: Float) -> Self {
        Self { radians }
    }
}

impl<'a> Measure<'a> for Angle<'a> {
    type Underlying = Float;

    fn name() -> &'static str {
        "angle"
    }

    fn default_unit() -> &'static str {
        "radian"
    }

    fn in_default_unit(&self) -> Self::Underlying {
        self.radians
    }

    fn from_default_unit(m: Self::Underlying) -> Self {
        Self::from_radians(m)
    }
}
```

I want to add common operations like overloading the `+` operator and similar, but I want to do this in such a way that it's linked to the `Measure` trait so I don't have to create it for every `Measure`.

I've tried making an intermediate class for operations that `Angle` could `Deref` but ran into some issues with lifetimes, and I think that route might actually be impossible.

This seems to me like it's a common enough need that there's a solution. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, primarily involving either macros or procedural macros. This method is actually pretty well described in [one of Shepmaster's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38815035/1129436), but the route I'm going to take will probably use the [derive_more](https://github.com/JelteF/derive_more) crate which will allow me to very easily provide these convenience functions.

Then I can just

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate derive_more;

#[derive(Add)]
struct Angle {
    radians: Float,
}
```