# How to combine all operator overloading combinations into a single trait in Rust?

Tags: rust

Is there a good way to combine all operator overloading combinations into a single trait in Rust?  As discussed, in the question [How to implement idiomatic operator overloading for values and references in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811387/how-to-implement-idiomatic-operator-overloading-for-values-and-references-in-rus), there are four different combinations for operator overloading binary operators: (ref,ref), (ref,val), (val,ref), and (val,val).  Further, there's a number of macros and such for helping define these routines.  My question is how to require all of these combinations in a sane way through a trait or another mechanism.  Consider the following code that attempts to create an algebra for a general float/real type:

```rust
// Create some random type that we want to represent as a Real
#[derive(Debug,Clone)]
struct Foo <Real> {
    x : Real,
    y : Real,
}

// Add the algebra for Foo
impl <Real> std::ops::Add <&'_ Foo<Real>> for &'_ Foo <Real>
where
    for <'a> &'a Real : std::ops::Add<&'a Real,Output=Real>
{
    type Output = Foo <Real>;
    fn add(self, other : &'_ Foo <Real>) -> Self::Output {
        Foo {
            x : &self.x + &other.x,
            y : &self.y + &other.y,
        }
    }
}
impl <Real> std::ops::Add <Foo<Real>> for &'_ Foo <Real>
where
    for <'a> &'a Real : std::ops::Add<Real,Output=Real>
{
    type Output = Foo <Real>;
    fn add(self, other : Foo <Real>) -> Self::Output {
        Foo {
            x : &self.x + other.x,
            y : &self.y + other.y,
        }
    }
}
impl <Real> std::ops::Add <&'_ Foo<Real>> for Foo <Real>
where
    for <'a> Real : std::ops::Add<&'a Real,Output=Real>
{
    type Output = Foo <Real>;
    fn add(self, other : &'_ Foo <Real>) -> Self::Output {
        Foo {
            x : self.x + &other.x,
            y : self.y + &other.y,
        }
    }
}
impl <Real> std::ops::Add <Foo<Real>> for Foo <Real>
where
    Real : std::ops::Add<Real,Output=Real>
{
    type Output = Foo <Real>;
    fn add(self, other : Foo <Real>) -> Self::Output {
        Foo {
            x : self.x + other.x,
            y : self.y + other.y,
        }
    }
}

// Compute a function on a slice of Reals.  This should work for f64 and Foo <f64>
fn foo <Real> (x : &[Real]) -> Real
where
    for <'a> &'a Real :
        std::ops::Add<&'a Real,Output=Real> +
        std::ops::Add<Real,Output=Real> +
        Clone,
    for <'a> Real :
        std::ops::Add<&'a Real,Output=Real> +
        std::ops::Add<Real,Output=Real> +
        Clone,
    Real : Clone
{
    (&x[0]+x[1].clone())+&x[2]
}

// Run foo on two different types
fn main() {
    let x = vec![1.2,2.3,3.4];
    let _x = foo::<f64>(&x);
    println!("{:?}",_x);
    let y : Vec <Foo<f64>>= x.into_iter().map(|z|Foo{x:z,y:z+1.0}).collect();
    let _y = foo::<Foo<f64>>(&y);
    println!("{:?}",_y);
}
```

The routine `foo` places a requirement both on `Real` and its reference `for <'a> &'a Real` to complete the algebra.  Now, this is pretty verbose and will only get worse as we add `Mul`, `Div`, etc.  I'd like to either have a single trait for `Real` or at least a single trait for `Real` and `for <'a> &'a Real`.  That said, I can't quite figure out a definition for it.  Typically, I'd place all of the definitions in a new trait such as:

```rust
trait MyFloat :        
    std::ops::Add <REFSELF,Output = NOREFSELF> +
    std::ops::Add <NOREFSELF,Output = NOREFSELF>
where
    Self : std::marker::Sized,
{}                                                  
impl <T> MyFloat for T where T:         
    std::ops::Add <REFSELF,Output = NOREFSELF> +
    std::ops::Add <NOREFSELF,Output = NOREFSELF>          
{}
```

But, this is already getting odd.  We need the output to always be the non-reference form of the type and we want the right hand side to be either the reference form or the non-reference form of the type.  However, as far as I know, there's not a mechanism for achieving this by manipulating `Self`.

Is there a good way for combining these definitions into a single trait?

Comment: that what [`num`](https://github.com/rust-num/num) is for

Comment: @Stargateur Unless I'm missing something, num covers the (val,val) situation and then relies on the `Copy` trait.  Which trait allows all of the different combinations of ref or not?