# How can I implement an operator like Add for a reference type so that I can add more than two values at once?

Tags: rust, addition

I'd like to make an immutable, by-reference data type with addition a bit like this:

```
use std::ops::Add;

struct Point {
    x: i64,
    y: i64,
}

impl<'a> Add for &'a Point {
    type Output = Point;
    fn add(self, other: &Point) -> Point {
        Point {
            x: self.x + &other.x,
            y: self.y + &other.y,
        }
    }
}
```

[How do I implement the Add trait for a reference to a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005134/how-do-i-implement-the-add-trait-for-a-reference-to-a-struct) suggests implementing `Add` on the reference type.

I can do this, where `a` and `b` are `Point`s:

```
let c = &a + &b;
let d = &c + &b;
```

but not this:

```
let d = &a + &b + &b;
```

I don't mind the `&` signs, but not being able to chain adds doesn't look good to me. I want to implement multiplication (`z = a + b * c;` or if I must, `z = &a + &b * &c;`), it would look clearer if I didn't have to create a temporary variable.

Is there a way to get this to work cleanly? Bracketing doesn't seem to help.

I understand what's going on, `&a + &b` gives a `Point` not a `&Point`, which suggests that I could implement both `add(&Point, Point)` and `add(&Point, &Point)` - but now there are 4 cases in total to get all combinations working since `a + b * c` and `a * b + c` have different precedence / parse trees after all. Is there a nicer way?

I'd also like to avoid unnecessary copying in the non-reference versions. I'm returning a new object anyway, so cloning the inputs first seems a waste of time to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would probably just implement `Add` of a reference to a value:

```
impl<'a> Add<&'a Point> for Point {
    type Output = Point;
    fn add(self, other: &'a Point) -> Point {
        Point {
            x: self.x + &other.x,
            y: self.y + &other.y,
        }
    }
}
```

> Bracketing doesn't seem to help.

You can take a reference to the result of part of the expression:

```
let d = &(&a + &b) + &b;
```

I'm not sure if that looks better or not to you.

> now there are 4 cases in total

There's actually 4 cases *per operation*: `(T, T)`, `(T, &T)`, `(&T, T)`, `(&T, &T)`.

> Is there a nicer way?

Not really, but that's because of your next requirement...

> I'd also like to avoid unnecessary copying in the non-reference versions

That's why the operations consume by value, to allow you to reuse any potential allocations. In the case of the `Point`, it's (ahem) pointless because the structs are so small. It's more believable for types like `Vec`.

---

All that being said, people usually use a macro to avoid the drudgery of writing the same thing over and over. For example, the [standard library has a macro that assumes the types implement `Copy`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.18.0/src/libcore/internal_macros.rs#L34-L70). If you want to *reuse* allocation, however, that means you do not want all 4 implementations to be the same. At best you might be able to write two  implementations `(&T, &T)` and `(T, &T)` and forward from the remaining two variants.

See also:

- [How do I implement the Add trait for a reference to a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28005134/155423)