# A generic scalar multiply a generic vector

Tags: rust, operators, traits

I am new to Rust. I am trying to implement my own `Vec3` toolkit.

I am implementing `scalar * vector` and `vector * scalar` operations, my current code

```rust
use std::ops::Mul;
use num_traits::real::Real;

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Vec3<T> (pub T, pub T, pub T);

impl<T: Copy + Clone> Vec3<T> {
    pub fn x(&self) -> T { self.0 }
    pub fn y(&self) -> T { self.1 }
    pub fn z(&self) -> T { self.2 }
}

// Math operation
impl <T: Real> Mul<T> for Vec3<T> {
    type Output = Self;
    fn mul(self, other: T) -> Self::Output {
        Self(self.x() * other, self.y() * other, self.z() * other)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = 3.;
    let v = Vec3(1., 2., 3.);
    let result = v * a;
    // this will throw an error
    // let result = a * v;
    println!("{} {} {}", result.0, result.1, result.2)
}
```

However, currently it only supports `vector * scalar`. `scalar * vector` will throw an error.

My question is, how to implement the LHS version of multiplication. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55266061/how-to-implement-bidirectional-lhs-and-rhs-operators-in-rust), but it seems that you should call the macro manually for each of `f16`, `f32`, `f64`, etc. But here I want a generic version for `Vec3<T>`.

<del>I've also tried this for `scalar * vector`</del>

```
impl <T: Real> Mul<Vec3<T>> for T {
    type Output = Vec3<T>;
    fn mul(self, other: Vec3<T>) -> Self::Output {
        Vec3(self * other.x(), self * other.y(), self * other.z())
    }
}
```

<del>But got an error
`` type parameter `T` must be covered by another type when it appears before the first local type (`vec3::Vec3<T>`) ``</del>

### Update

Thanks [Chayim Friedman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7884305/chayim-friedman) for pointing out why the above workaround is not allowed by the compiler.

However, I still wonder the best way to implement a commutative `Mul` operator for generic type.

Comment: Simply put you can't implement it that way because someone might want to implement both `Real` and `Mul<Vec3<T>>` for their type and those would collide with your implementation. See  [What exactly is the requirement for "covering" a type & why does a single element tuple satisfy it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75075748/what-exactly-is-the-requirement-for-covering-a-type-why-does-a-single-elemen) for a workaround.

Comment: Wow, there was a blog post in This Week In Rust this week about this exactly: https://ohadravid.github.io/posts/2023-05-coherence-and-errors/.