# How to implement Add trait without consuming the value

Tags: rust, traits

When implementing the `Add` trait (and a few others, like `Mul`, `Sub`, etc.) for a simple struct one has to fully consume the struct value, thus its later use is  not possible.

At the same time, built in primitives (`u8`, `usize`, etc.) implement `Add` while allowing using it after `add` was called.

How can I implement `Add` for my structs to be able to use it after calling `add`?

```rust
use std::ops::Add;

struct I(usize);
impl Add for I {
    type Output = Self;
    fn add(self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
        I(self.0 + rhs.0)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = 123;
    let b = a + a; // no error

    let a1 = I(123);
    let b1 = a1 + a1;

    println!("b={}", b);
}
```

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `a1`
  --> src/main.rs:16:19
   |
15 |     let a1 = I(123);
   |         -- move occurs because `a1` has type `I`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
16 |     let b1 = a1 + a1;
   |              --   ^^ value used here after move
   |              |
   |              value moved here
```

Comment: You could `impl Deref` and use `*a1`, I imagine?

Comment: @jhpratt can you elaborate on your answer pls, and maybe provide an example implementation?

Comment: Ryan's answer should suffice, but I'll give you an example of what I mentioned as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to add `#[derive(Copy, Clone)]` to the struct, and then instead of consuming the value, it'll consume a copy.

Answer (score 1):

You can `impl Deref` and dereference the value. This will work for types that are simple wrappers around an `Add` type.

```
use std::ops::{Add, Deref};

struct I(usize);
impl Add for I {
    type Output = Self;
    fn add(self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
        I(self.0 + rhs.0)
    }
}

impl Deref for I {
    type Target = usize;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = 123;
    let b = a + a; // no error

    let a1 = I(123);

    // Note the dereferences.
    let b1 = *a1 + *a1;

    println!("b={}", b);
}
```

NB: Ryan's answer should suffice in this case, as `usize` is a clone type.

Comment: I think it's quite odd to do that like that you just write `a1.0 + a1.0` that doesn't really solve the problem if your type is not `Copy`

Comment: @Stargateur Things aren't always in the same module.

Comment: [Is it considered a bad practice to implement Deref for newtypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45086595/155423)