# How do I overload an operator using higher ranked trait bounds?

Tags: rust

Though this has been discussed before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34630695/how-to-write-a-trait-bound-for-adding-two-references-of-a-generic-type) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29184358/how-do-i-require-a-generic-type-implement-an-operation-like-add-sub-mul-or-di), I can't quite make a simple example work.  In the code

```
// Create some random type that we want to represent as a Real
struct Foo<Real> {
    x: Real,
    y: Real,
}

// Add the algebra for Foo
impl<Real> std::ops::Add for Foo<Real>
where
    Real: std::ops::Add<Output = Real> + std::ops::Mul<Output = Real>,
{
    type Output = Self;
    fn add(self, other: Self) -> Self::Output {
        Foo {
            x: self.x + other.x,
            y: self.y + other.y,
        }
    }
}

impl<Real> std::ops::Mul for Foo<Real>
where
    Real: std::ops::Add<Output = Real> + std::ops::Mul<Output = Real>,
{
    type Output = Self;
    fn mul(self, other: Self) -> Self::Output {
        Foo {
            x: self.x * other.x,
            y: self.y * other.y,
        }
    }
}

// Compute a function on a slice of Reals
fn foo<Real>(x: &[Real]) -> Real
where
    for<'a> &'a Real: std::ops::Add<Output = Real> + std::ops::Mul<Output = Real>,
{
    &(&x[0] + &x[1]) * &x[2]
}

// Run foo on two different types
fn main() {
    let x = vec![1.2, 2.3, 3.4];
    let _x = foo::<f64>(&x);
    let y: Vec<Foo<f64>> = x.into_iter().map(|z| Foo { x: z, y: z + 1.0 }).collect();
    let _y = foo::<Foo<f64>>(&y);
}
```

We get the compiler error:

```
error[E0277]: cannot add `&'a Foo<f64>` to `&'a Foo<f64>`
  --> src/main.rs:47:14
   |
47 |     let _y = foo::<Foo<f64>>(&y);
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no implementation for `&'a Foo<f64> + &'a Foo<f64>`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::ops::Add` is not implemented for `&'a Foo<f64>`
note: required by `foo`
  --> src/main.rs:35:1
   |
35 | / fn foo<Real>(x: &[Real]) -> Real
36 | | where
37 | |     for<'a> &'a Real: std::ops::Add<Output = Real> + std::ops::Mul<Output = Real>,
38 | | {
39 | |     &(&x[0] + &x[1]) * &x[2]
40 | | }
   | |_^

error[E0277]: cannot multiply `&'a Foo<f64>` to `&'a Foo<f64>`
  --> src/main.rs:47:14
   |
47 |     let _y = foo::<Foo<f64>>(&y);
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no implementation for `&'a Foo<f64> * &'a Foo<f64>`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::ops::Mul` is not implemented for `&'a Foo<f64>`
note: required by `foo`
  --> src/main.rs:35:1
   |
35 | / fn foo<Real>(x: &[Real]) -> Real
36 | | where
37 | |     for<'a> &'a Real: std::ops::Add<Output = Real> + std::ops::Mul<Output = Real>,
38 | | {
39 | |     &(&x[0] + &x[1]) * &x[2]
40 | | }
   | |_^
```

This seems to imply that the definitions of `Add` and `Mul` are incorrect.  Is there an easy way to fix the definitions?  In case it makes a difference, it's my desire to have `Add` and `Mul` not take ownership of their arguments.  Rather, I'd like to have each operator allocate new memory and then give ownership of that variable to the calling function.

---

### Edit 1

As pointed out, this is a duplicate of the following two questions combined

- [How do I implement the Add trait for a reference to a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005134/how-do-i-implement-the-add-trait-for-a-reference-to-a-struct)
- [How to write a trait bound for adding two references of a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34630695/how-to-write-a-trait-bound-for-adding-two-references-of-a-generic-type)

For posterity's sake, here's a working code from @Shepmaster:

```
use std::ops::{Add, Mul};

// Create some random type that we want to represent as a Real
struct Foo<Real> {
    x: Real,
    y: Real,
}

// Add the algebra for Foo
impl<Real> Add for &'_ Foo<Real>
where
    for<'a> &'a Real: Add<Output = Real> + Mul<Output = Real>,
{
    type Output = Foo<Real>;

    fn add(self, other: Self) -> Self::Output {
        Foo {
            x: &self.x + &other.x,
            y: &self.y + &other.y,
        }
    }
}

impl<Real> Mul for &'_ Foo<Real>
where
    for<'a> &'a Real: Add<Output = Real> + Mul<Output = Real>,
{
    type Output = Foo<Real>;

    fn mul(self, other: Self) -> Self::Output {
        Foo {
            x: &self.x * &other.x,
            y: &self.y * &other.y,
        }
    }
}

// Compute a function on a slice of Reals
fn foo<Real>(x: &[Real]) -> Real
where
    for<'a> &'a Real: std::ops::Add<Output = Real> + std::ops::Mul<Output = Real>,
{
    &(&x[0] + &x[1]) * &x[2]
}

// Run foo on two different types
fn main() {
    let x = vec![1.2, 2.3, 3.4];
    let _x = foo::<f64>(&x);
    let y: Vec<Foo<f64>> = x.into_iter().map(|z| Foo { x: z, y: z + 1.0 }).collect();
    let _y = foo::<Foo<f64>>(&y);
}
```

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How do I implement the Add trait for a reference to a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28005134/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6135557efef81ce47ab2cca60f9133c0).

Comment: It is particularly worth noting that, if something implements trait `T`, it does not follow automatically that trait `T` is also implemented for the reference version of the trait. Only in certain cases is that true. The duplicate suggestion by @Shepmaster covers the rest

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks for the fix on the playground.  Though this situation is similar to your link, it's slightly different due to the higher rank trait bound on `Real`, which was also throwing me off.  Anyway, if you want to post that code as an answer, I'll accept it.  If everyone truly thinks this is just a duplicate of multiple questions, we can close things out.

Comment: @wyer33 it's a combination of the question you already found (HRTB for the requirements on `Real`) and implementing the trait for a reference (the Q&A I added in a comment). Since SO allows for a question to be answered by multiple duplicates, that seems like a reasonable solution to me, but I'm always open to well-reasoned discussion to change my mind.

Comment: We can leave it as a duplicate.  I made one final edit with the working code in case anyone runs across the same difficulty.