# Cannot overload add operator on a struct containing a Cow because I cannot return value referencing local data

Tags: rust

I'm implementing basic operations for matrices on a generic field `F`. In doing so, I want to overload the add operator for the matrix type. The matrix type contains a `Cow` either owning or borrowing `F`. I want the resulting matrix sum to borrow the `F` of the added matrix regardless if it owns or borrows `F`.

The compiler complains that I return a reference created inside the function, but I don't understand why. It seems to me I'm referencing an input argument of the function and not data created locally. Here's my minimal example:

```
use std::{
    borrow::{Borrow, Cow},
    ops::Add,
};

pub trait Field {
    type FElt: Copy + Eq;

    fn zero(&self) -> Self::FElt;
    fn add(&self, a: Self::FElt, b: Self::FElt) -> Self::FElt;
}

pub struct Mat<'a, F: Clone + Eq + Field> {
    field: Cow<'a, F>,
    rows: usize,
    cols: usize,
    data: Vec<F::FElt>,
}

impl<'a, F: Clone + Eq + Field> Mat<'a, F> {
    pub fn zero(field: &'a F, rows: usize, cols: usize) -> Self {
        if rows == 0 || cols == 0 {
            panic!("Empty matrix");
        }

        Self {
            field: Cow::Borrowed(field),
            rows,
            cols,
            data: vec![field.zero(); rows * cols],
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, F: Clone + Eq + Field> Add for Mat<'a, F> {
    type Output = Self;

    fn add(self, other: Self) -> Self::Output {
        if self.field != other.field {
            panic!("Cannot add matrices: fields do not match");
        }
        if self.rows != other.rows || self.cols != other.cols {
            panic!("Cannot add matrices: dimensions do not match");
        }

        let f: &F = self.field.borrow();
        let mut sum = Mat::zero(f, self.rows, self.cols);
        for i in 0..self.rows * self.cols {
            sum.data[i] = f.add(self.data[i], other.data[i]);
        }
        sum
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local data `self.field`
  --> src/main.rs:51:9
   |
46 |         let f: &F = self.field.borrow();
   |                     ---------- `self.field` is borrowed here
...
51 |         sum
   |         ^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

Comment: I suspect you don't want a `Cow` for your field, but instead want an `Rc` (or more likely a `PhantomData`).

Comment: I didn't know about `Rc`. This is exactly what I wanted, thank you! `PhantomData` would not work as I need to store the information about the field `F` (and I want to avoid repeating it in every element of the vector `data`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems to me I'm referencing an input argument of the function and not data created locally.

`self` may not have been *created* locally, but it is *moved into* the `add` method (which takes `self`), so it will still be destroyed when the function returns. If the output were allowed to reference it, the reference would become dangling as soon as the function returned.

If you want the output to borrow from the input, you must take the input as a reference, which means implementing `Add` for `&'b Mat<'a, F>` instead of `Mat<'a, F>`. See [How do I implement the Add trait for a reference to a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28005134/3650362) Note that the `Output` type must be `Mat<'b, F>` instead of `Mat<'a, F>`.

There's another, simpler solution for the problem as posed. Borrowing doesn't work because the `Cow` was mooved in to the function. Why not just move it back out? An easy way to do this is to modify `self` and return it rather than creating `sum` inside the function.

```
    fn add(mut self, other: Self) -> Self::Output {
        /* ... */

        for i in 0..self.rows * self.cols {
            self.data[i] = self.field.add(self.data[i], other.data[i]);
        }
        self
    }
```

Not only do you avoid a potentially expensive clone of `field`, but you also reuse `data`'s buffer this way.

Comment: "Borrowing doesn't work because the Cow was **mooved** in to the function." => I see what you did here...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Implementing `Add` for a reference works but I want to implement `Add` for all four combinations of `Mat` and `&Mat` such that I can write a + b. But I guess all my trouble comes from the fact that I picked `Cow` where I should have picked `Rc` as Jmb suggested.

Comment: Your simpler solution looks weird to me. As I understand it, if I write `a + b`, I will get the sum but matrix `a` will also mutate into the sum in the process which I don't want.

Comment: @gwafotapa `a` is consumed by the expression `a + b`, so there's no way for the code to observe that. This is also how `String` implements `Add<&str>`, for example.

Comment: @trentcl I hadn't thought about that. I understand your intent now. That's a great solution. Even though I'm now using `Rc` in my code, I can benefit from this and that's a good answer to my original problem.