# Simplify operator overloading for struct and &struct?

Tags: struct, rust, operator-overloading, traits

Consider the following vector struct:

```
struct Vec3([f64; 3]);
```

I'd like to be able to use the `+` operator when dealing with these vectors. So I started off with:

```
impl Add for Vec3 {
    type Output = Vec3;
    fn add(self, other: Vec3) -> Vec3 {
        Vec3::new_with(self[0] + other[0], self[1] + other[1], self[2] + other[2])
    }
}
```

Which works fine, until the point that I don't want these structs to be moved, we can work with their references instead, so I end up doing 3 more *impls*:

```
impl Add for &Vec3 {
    type Output = Vec3;
    fn add(self, other: &Vec3) -> Vec3 {
        Vec3::new_with(self[0] + other[0], self[1] + other[1], self[2] + other[2])
    }
}

impl Add<Vec3> for &Vec3 {
    type Output = Vec3;
    fn add(self, other: Vec3) -> Vec3 {
        Vec3::new_with(self[0] + other[0], self[1] + other[1], self[2] + other[2])
    }
}

impl Add<&Vec3> for Vec3 {
    type Output = Vec3;
    fn add(self, other: &Vec3) -> Vec3 {
        Vec3::new_with(self[0] + other[0], self[1] + other[1], self[2] + other[2])
    }
}
```

All of these `add` methods have exactly the same implementation. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57021762/13679671

Comment: Absolutely, thanks a bunch! This was hard to find.