# How do I implement Into<MyType> for &str

Tags: rust

I have a custom type `pub struct Foo` and I'd like to be able to say strings can be converted to `Foo` types. I'm trying to do `impl<'a> Into<Foo> for &'a str`, but I know from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594374/overload-operators-with-different-rhs-type/24594911#24594911) that I can't do that. What other options do I have?

For context, I'm trying to do something like

```
trait Foo {
    type ArgType;
    fn new<I: Into<Self::ArgType>>(arg: I) -> Self;
}

struct MyType;
impl Into<MyType> for str {
    fn into(self) -> MyType { MyType }
}

struct Bar;
impl Foo for Bar {
    type ArgType = MyType;
    fn new<I: Into<MyType>>(arg: I) -> Bar { Bar }
}
```

Comment: (For converting from strings you should normally use the [`FromStr`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html) trait; the method [`str.parse()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse) will then also be able to produce your type. If you have a type that can be converted from a string without the possibility of errors, ignore this advice.)

Comment: Well the thing is that I want `new` to be able to take arguments that convert to `MyType`, for example. The emphasis is not on converting from strings, it's from converting strings to my type

Answer (score 8):

As Chris Morgan noted, [`FromStr`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html) is an option, [`From<&str>`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) would be another. The latter would give you a builtin implementation of `Into<Foo>` for `&str`, too (because there is a blanket impl of `Into<U> For T where U: From<T>`).

Comment: Ah yes `From<&str>` worked perfectly, and it makes sense because `impl From<&str> for Bar` doesn't have the orphan impl issue as before. Thanks!

Comment: See also [When should I implement std::convert::From vs std::convert::Into?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29812530/155423).