# Templating the return type as well as RHS type for the ops::Mul trait

Tags: rust, operator-overloading

I want to overload an operator trait for multiple types. In this example case, a 3D vector might be multiplied by a scalar (scaling the vector components and returning a vector) or another vector (computing the dot-product and returning a scalar).

I needed a similar solution to the one offered in '[How can an operator be overloaded for different RHS types and return values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594374/how-can-an-operator-be-overloaded-for-different-rhs-types-and-return-values)'. Here's approximately the code for the accepted solution in the original code. I removed the references as they don't seem to be needed.

```
use std::ops;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Vector3D {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
    z: f32,
}

trait MulVector3D<ResType> {
    fn do_mul(self, rhs: Vector3D) -> ResType;
}


impl MulVector3D<Vector3D> for f32 {
    fn do_mul(self, rhs: Vector3D) -> Vector3D {
        Vector3D {
            x: self * rhs.x,
            y: self * rhs.y,
            z: self * rhs.z,
        }
    }
}

impl MulVector3D<f32> for Vector3D {
    fn do_mul(self, rhs: Vector3D) -> f32 {
        self.x * rhs.x + self.y * rhs.y + self.z * rhs.z
    }
}

impl<ResType, RHS: MulVector3D<ResType>> ops::Mul for Vector3D {
    fn mul(self, rhs: RHS) -> ResType {
        rhs.do_mul(self)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Vector3D {
        x: 1.0,
        y: 2.0,
        z: 3.0,
    };

    let b = a * -1.0;
    let c = a * b;

    println!("{:?}", a);
    println!("{:?}", b);
    println!("{:?}", c);
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work for me, and I wonder if the language specification changed with regards to this. I am getting the following error message:

```
error[E0207]: the type parameter `ResType` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  --> src/main.rs:31:6
   |
31 | impl<ResType, RHS: MulVector3D<ResType>> ops::Mul for Vector3D {
   |      ^^^^^^^ unconstrained type parameter

error[E0207]: the type parameter `RHS` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  --> src/main.rs:31:15
   |
31 | impl<ResType, RHS: MulVector3D<ResType>> ops::Mul for Vector3D {
   |               ^^^ unconstrained type parameter
```

I did some searching about it, and to be honest, I don't even know how to phrase this question compactly enough to get a meaningful answer. AFAIK, the `ResType` template parameter is indeed unconstrained, but I don't see why that's an issue. And as for the `RHS`, that's actually constrained to implement the `MulVector3D<ResType>` trait. So again, I don't see what the error message is trying to tell me.

Can you explain the error messsage to me? Is it actually possible that I'm trying to do or it was disallowed since the original question by some language change?

Comment: Which answer did you use [from that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594374/how-can-an-operator-be-overloaded-for-different-rhs-types-and-return-values)? The one that is accepted or the one with more upvotes?

Comment: You should attempt to explain, in *words*, what you are trying to accomplish. You've got various syntax mistakes that hide the meaning.

Comment: Shepmaster: What are those syntax mistakes? This code should is pretty much the same as the one in the accepted answer. (I was going with the accepted answer).

Comment: Why did you choose to ignore the upvoted answer that shows how to do it?

Comment: Are you implying that the highest voted answer is the solution? In which case the reason I ignored it because it because it wasn't accepted. Normally updates of such kind shows up in the comment of the original answer or at least a comment will imply that this solution is outdated and use the other answer. I thank you, I will give a try.