# Implementing the same trait for different type constraits

Tags: rust

I have a struct I need to implement multiplication for. The multiplication can either be with a value I can turn into some scalar (`i8`, `usize` etc.) or the same as the struct

```rust
struct Eg<const N: usize, T> ([T; N]);

impl<const N: usize, T, Q> std::ops::Mul<Q> for Eg<N, T> where Q: From<isize> { 
    type Output = Self;

    fn mul(self, rhs: Q) -> Self::Output { }
}

impl<const N: usize, const P: usize, T> std::ops::Mul<Eg<P, T>> for Eg<N, T> { 
    type Output = Eg<P, T>;

    fn mul(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output { }
}
```

Since `Eg` does not implement `From<isize>` the compiler would have to chose use the second option. Rust isn't a fan of this and says there are conflicting implementations of trait 'std::ops::Mul'.

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24554738/). This has not been updated (aside for editing) for over 8 years and I assume things will have changed since then

If there's any way I can specify what implementation the compiler looks at for specific multipliers (rhs) that would be very helpful. Thanks

---

The full code is fairly large and would be less helpful here than the sample given. the main points (I think) are still maintained:

- Different number of constants for rach implementation (with a different number of generics in the full code)
- Different output types
- Differet multiplier types (`Q` vs `Eg<P, T>`)

Comment: What is `Q`? I don't see it declared.

Comment: The second `impl` also has a generic parameter `N` that is not used anywhere in either the trait or the type it's being implemented on, which is disallowed -- there would be no way to specify this parameter in usage of the implementation.

Comment: Sorry. Missed them out. The code should be correct now

Comment: `Q` is still not declared on the second `impl`.

Comment: `Q` shouldn't really have been there sorry

Comment: I was not able to reproduce, your code seems to compile just fine: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f22b053afc4901289f0366fd56bc4db3). The linked Q&A is still the behavior but isn't applicable here because that is due to constraints for *foreign* types. Your `Eg` type is local and the compiler is plainly able to see that `From<isize>` is not implemented.